# Node: all data is saved except the array field

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a problem saving this object that has an array as a property, everything is being saved except the array.I don't know what point I'm missing, if the problem was the approach to solving the problem if there is a better way to solve it
json sent

````
data:'2020-08-14'
hora:'21:04'
identificador:'MSG 001'
mensagem:'TEST 001'
periocidade:(7) ['Segunda-Feira', 'Terça-Feira', 'Quarta-Feira', 'Quinta-Feira', 'Sexta-Feira', 'Sabado', 'Domingo']
__proto__:Object```

Model

``new Schema({
    identificador: {
        type: String
    },
    hora: {
        type: String
    },
    data: {
        type: String
    },
    mensagem: {
        type: String
    },
    ativo: {
        type: Boolean,
        default :true
    },
    periodicidade : [{
        type : String
    }],
    date_time : { 
        type : Date, 
        default: Date.now 
    }``
Action

``routes.route('/add').post(function(req, res) {
    let regra = new Mensagem(req.body);
    regra.save()
        .then(regra => {
            res.status(200).json({'msg': 'added successfully'});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new failed');
        });
});``
````

Comment: the title should be...Node: all data is saved except the array

Comment: try `Mensagem.create(req.body).then()` instead

Comment: same problem, sad

Comment: a wrong letter, in the property in the model

Comment: right periocidade and periodicidade

Comment: this, I was like crazy hours, looking for the problem kkkkkkkkk